# New version of Rake Pipeline doesn't like my config.ru

Tags: ember.js, rack, rake-pipeline

I'm working on an Ember.js project (around 0.9.8.x, if it matters) which was built with [ember-skeleton](https://github.com/interline/ember-skeleton). I recently made the mistake of haphazardly running `bundle update` and my version of [rake-pipeline](https://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline) jumped from 0.6.0 to 0.8.0, and I get this error when I make a request of my development server:

> NoMethodError at /
> undefined method `invoke' for "Assetfile":String

The specific error comes here:

> ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@project/bundler/gems/rake-pipeline-ee992cbcda51/lib/rake-pipeline/middleware.rb: in call, line 32

but I would guess the real start of it is in the first few lines of `config.ru`:

```
require 'rake-pipeline'
require 'rake-pipeline/middleware'
use Rake::Pipeline::Middleware, 'Assetfile'
```

The stack trace doesn't appear to touch my code at all; in fact, if I understand this error properly, it doesn't even touch my `Assetfile`.

Is this a bug, or did something change in rake-pipeline? Will it be easier to downgrade rake-pipeline (if so, to where?) or is there something I can fix in `config.ru`?

ETA: I'm hopping back in the `rake-pipeline` project history a few dozen commits at a time. Going back to [the end of October](https://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline/commit/986129d378a6de2ff43df8d7439acb178a162a81), I get different errors:

> TypeError at /
> can't convert Fixnum into String
>
> ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@project/bundler/gems/rake-pipeline-986129d378a6/lib/rake-pipeline/manifest_entry.rb:9:in `parse'

When I hop [all the way back to April 2012](https://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline/commit/543f4322fe70facee9572d29ddabf7f090dad68a) I get a working version. So my project is back in business, but I'd love to know what blew up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [rake-pipeline now expects a Rake::Pipeline::Project object as an argument, not a string.](https://github.com/listrophy/ember-skeleton/commit/9da40a049d6d8be37b29742934555f70af444a47) Replacing the third line of that `config.ru` with this makes it work:

```
use Rake::Pipeline::Middleware, Rake::Pipeline::Project.new('Assetfile')
```

Thanks, GitHub!

Comment: Thanks pjmorse..Fixed it for me!